# Setting a background image within a set Tkinter animation framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, background, lag

I am currently working on a fruit ninja project for a class. Everything functionally works fine, however, when I try to put in a background image for the game runs extremely slow. In order for the game to look polished, I need everything to work smoothly while having the background of the game show. Other solutions I have come across and have tried to understand simply do not work or the file never ends up running.

FYI: I am working in python 2.7.

I have tried some other suggestions for adding a background, such as using a label function, however, when I try to implement it I get a variety of errors and it just does not seem to work in my animation framework.

```py
def run(width=300, height=300):
    def redrawAllWrapper(canvas, data):
        canvas.delete(ALL)
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, data.width, data.height,
                                fill='white', width=0)
        redrawAll(canvas, data)
        canvas.update()    

    def mousePressedWrapper(event, canvas, data):
        mousePressed(event, data)
        redrawAllWrapper(canvas, data)

    def keyPressedWrapper(event, canvas, data):
        keyPressed(event, data)
        redrawAllWrapper(canvas, data)

    def timerFiredWrapper(canvas, data):
        timerFired(data)
        redrawAllWrapper(canvas, data)
        # pause, then call timerFired again
        canvas.after(data.timerDelay, timerFiredWrapper, canvas, data)
    # Set up data and call init
    class Struct(object): pass
    data = Struct()
    data.width = width
    data.height = height
    data.timerDelay = 10 # milliseconds
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # prevents resizing window

    init(data)
    # create the root and the canvas
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=data.width, height=data.height)
    canvas.configure(bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    # set up events
    root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:
                            mousePressedWrapper(event, canvas, data))
    root.bind("<Key>", lambda event:
                            keyPressedWrapper(event, canvas, data))
    timerFiredWrapper(canvas, data)
    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()  # blocks until window is closed
    print("bye!")

run(1200, 700)
```

with my current framework, I write all the necessary code within the init, timerFired, redrawAll, keyPressed, and mousePressed functions above this run function.

With my current implementation of the background. I use PhotoImage on a 1200 x 700 gif file and draw the image across the whole screen in the redrawAll function (which is called every 10 milliseconds). Without drawing this one image, my game runs very smoothly, however, upon drawing the image in redrawAll, the game lags significantly, so I do know the source of the lag is drawing the background image.

Here is the line of code that draws it in redrawAll:

canvas.create_image(data.width//2, data.height//2, image = data.background)

Is this only because I do it in redrawAll which continuously draws the image every time the function is called making it slow? Is simply having an image that large in Tkinter making it slow? What is the source?

This there a way to simply draw the image once on the background and have it never change? Or is there any way to not have lag? I just find it odd. Again, this is in python 2.7 on a Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you redraw all elements. `tkinter` works different than `pygame` or other frameworks. You don't have to redraw all elements. You can move elements on canvas without redrawing and canvas with display it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to remove and add again all elements to refresh screen. You can move elements and canvas will draw it correctly

This code create 1000 small rectangles and move them randomly on background.

Tested with Python 3.7 but on 2.7 should work too.

With `5_000` rectangles it slows down but it still works good (but not perfect). With `10_000` it slows down too much.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random

IMAGE_PATH = 'background.jpg'

class Struct(object):
    pass

def run(width=300, height=300):

    def init(data):
        # create 1000 rectangles in random position
        for _ in range(1000):
            x = random.randint(0, data.width)
            y = random.randint(0, data.height)
            data.data.append(canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill='red'))

    def mousePressedWrapper(event, canvas, data):
        #mousePressed(event, data)
        pass 

    def keyPressedWrapper(event, canvas, data):
        #keyPressed(event, data)
        pass

    def timerFiredWrapper(canvas, data):
        # move objects
        for rect_id in data.data:
            x = random.randint(-10, 10)
            y = random.randint(-10, 10)
            canvas.move(rect_id, x, y)

        # pause, then call timerFired again
        canvas.after(data.timerDelay, timerFiredWrapper, canvas, data)

    # Set up data and call init
    data = Struct()
    data.width = width
    data.height = height
    data.timerDelay = 10 # milliseconds
    data.data = [] # place for small red rectangles

    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # prevents resizing window

    # create the root and the canvas
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=data.width, height=data.height)
    canvas.configure(bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()

    #canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, data.width, data.height, fill='white', width=0)
    img = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH)
    img = img.resize((data.width, data.height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')

    init(data) # init after creating canvas because it create rectangles on canvas

    # set up events
    root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:
                            mousePressedWrapper(event, canvas, data))
    root.bind("<Key>", lambda event:
                            keyPressedWrapper(event, canvas, data))
    timerFiredWrapper(canvas, data)

    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()  # blocks until window is closed
    print("bye!")

run(1200, 700)
```